Error: SharePoint Designer does not support editing non-SharePoint sites
Newbie to SharePoint Designer.
When I attempt to open a SharePoint site in Designer 2013 I can see the following folder structure :-

However when I click the Open button I get the following error :-

I have SP1 installed & the spd2013-kb3114721-fullfile-x64-glb.exe update.
I have also deleted everything within the following locations :-
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache
The site was created within SharePoint & I can build lists, etc. so any hints, tips, ideas, etc. on how I can solve the error would be much appreciated.

Your SharePoint Online site is using classic ou modern experience? SharePoint Designer 2013 can only works with classic experience, not the modern UI.
